How to get the root from a hypergeometric function and plot it in the complex plane
I'm trying to reproduce the plot(Figure 3) of this paper. Here, the strip length's expression is given by the Equation.13
$t_\pm(z)= A_\pm \pm \iota \frac{z_t}{d}(\frac{z}{z_t})^d \times
{}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{d}{2(d-1)},  \frac{3d-2}{2(d-1)}, (\frac{z}{z_t})^{2d - 2}\right)
$
Where $A_\pm$ and $z_t$ expressions are given in Equation 14,
They are plotting $Im(z_t/z_h)$ and $Re(z_t/z_h)$, the root of $f(z)=0$, where $f(z)=1- \frac{z^3}{z_{h}^3}$ for $AdS_4$ and the critical extremal surfaces as given in the Eq.16
zt = (I \[CapitalDelta]t Gamma[1/(2 (-1 + d))])/(
  2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[d/(2 (-1 + d))]);

t[z_] = \[CapitalDelta]t/2 + (
   I z^d zt^(1 - d)
     Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, d/(2 (-1 + d)), 1 + d/(2 (-1 + d)), 
     z^(-2 + 2 d) zt^(2 - 2 d)])/d;

(*d=3 for AdS4*)

f[z_] = 1 - z^3/zh^3;

Solve[f[z] == 0, z];

xroot = {1, Re[-(-1)^(1/3)] // N, Re[(-1)^(2/3)] // N};

yroot = {0, Im[-(-1)^(1/3)] // N, Im[(-1)^(2/3)] // N};

plot1 = ListPlot[Transpose[{xroot, yroot}], 
   PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "BoldColor"}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
   PlotMarkers -> {"*", Medium}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 4}, {-1.5, 1.5}}];

xvalues = {2^(2/3) // N, Re[2^(2/3) Exp[(2 \[Pi] I)/3] // N], 
   Re[2^(2/3) Exp[(-2 \[Pi] I)/3] // N]};

yvalues = {0, Im[2^(2/3) Exp[(2 \[Pi] I)/3] // N], 
   Im[2^(2/3) Exp[(-2 \[Pi] I)/3] // N]};

plot2 = ListPlot[Transpose[{xvalues, yvalues}], PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "BoldColor"}, 
   PlotMarkers -> {"x", Medium}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 4}, {-1.5, 1.5}}];

Show[plot1, plot2]

I've plotted the roots of $f(z)=0$ and the critical extremal surfaces,
but I couldn't get the blue and green curves. Can anyone suggest how to do it?
